# What character creation tools exist for Earthdawn?

Tags: character-creation, tools, earthdawn

I am looking for a character builder for Earthdawn, preferably 3rd edition. As the editions are not that different, this is not an important detail for me.

I downloaded the Earthdawn Character Editor 0.46 from Holger von Rhein, but it is far from perfect.
Does anyone know a better one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [The Second Step](http://www.secondstep.dk/)

It *is* for second edition (which I use) not third; [but here is a list of changes](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5310/what-are-the-changes-in-the-third-edition-in-earthdawn)
It's fairly easy to use, prints character sheets in several formats.

I believe you can get it to work with 3rd fully, but I'm afraid I've not tried.

Comment: I was unable to use the free skill points, clicked on increase and nothing happened.

Comment: Pretty sure you can only do one free point/skill to begin with (might have to reread the RAW though)

Answer (score 3):

I remember having used **Benjamin Legangneux's EDCG (Earthdawn Character Generator)**, version 1.3e, released in 1997 for the first, original edition of ED. It was an excellent utility - and I think it's still available online, even though perhaps only at mirror and archive sites.

One such site is [the Earthdawn Blog](http://earthdawn.blogspot.com/2008/07/earthdawn-character-generators.html), which has an entire page dedicated to various Earthdawn character generators. I think it's well worth checking out, as it seems rather comprehensive, offering quite a number of options to choose from.